# How can I detect whether a vowel has a circumflex, grave accent (etc.) in C#?

Tags: c#, string, character, diacritics

I´ve found a long List of **variations of vowels**,
for example: Û, â, ê, é etc.

Is there a comfortable way to check all vowels and catch the ones,
which are **not** "normal" - vowels ?

Comment: _Normal_ is in the eye of the beholder. I guess you could check if it's in the ASCII range?

Comment: It gets more complicate than that as well, you can have combining characters so that you have the "normal" character in one codepoint and the accent in another, such as `"U\u0302"` which will produce the same as `"Û"`. My guess is that this question and answer will provide what you seek - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net - even though it is not a proper duplicate.

Comment: One approach would be to normalize each character to form D, and if it decomposes into something containing a diacritic (NonSpacingMark in the .NET categories), it would be one of those you call "not normal".

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between accent, circumflex, etc? If you just need to detect diacritics see this question: [How to check if Unicode character has diacritics in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349608/how-to-check-if-unicode-character-has-diacritics-in-net)